# Open Jquery-UI Dialog Box inside table not showing in right place?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, webforms

Here is the jQuery Code to Show the Dialog Box Dynamically.

```
function ShowDialog(id) {

        var x = $('btn_' + id).position();

        $("#dialog_" + id).dialog({
            title: "Description",
            position:{ my:"" },
            autoOpen: false,
            show: {
                effect: "blind",
                duration: 1000
            },
            hide: {
                effect: "explode",
                duration: 1000
            },
            position:
                 { my: "center", at: "center", of: window }
        });

        var theDialog = $("#dialog_" + id);
        theDialog.dialog("open");

    }
```

Here is Html Code for the gridview with generate dynamically.

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Description" ItemStyle-Width="80px">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    
                    <div id="dialog_1" style="display: none;">
                        <p>Details</p>
                    </div>

                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-sm btn_1" onclick="ShowDialog(1)">Show Detail</button>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
```

And Output is:

Should be open here

[image]

Comment: Not sure where you use `x` but you are missing a `.` or `#` in the selector of `var x = $('btn_' + id).position();`

Comment: Ok its class then how to calculate?

Comment: If it's a class use `$('.btn_' + id)`

Comment: Now tell me how to calculate position using x value

Answer (score 0):

Try writing `position: {  my: "right center", at: "right center"}` like this:

```
function ShowDialog(id) {

        var x = $('btn_' + id).position();

        $("#dialog_" + id).dialog({
            title: "Description",
            position:{ my:"" },
            autoOpen: false,
            show: {
                effect: "blind",
                duration: 1000
            },
            hide: {
                effect: "explode",
                duration: 1000
            },
            position:
                 { my: "right center", at: "right center", of: window }  // here
        });

        var theDialog = $("#dialog_" + id);
        theDialog.dialog("open");

    }
```

Comment: Its not working, instead of showing on top its CSS Style left showing 0px. Suggest me to calculate left pixels using jQuery and set to the position?